# Adding link button in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I wold like to add a linkbutton sort of in mvc webgrid which should invoke a javascript method.

I am now using:

```
hiddenDiv.Column("",style: "col1",format: @<text>
<button class="edit-book display-mode" id="@item.FacilityID">
    Select</button>
</text>)
```

which calls :

```
$('.edit-book').on('click', function () {
        $('#hiddendiv2').show();
        $('#facilitygrid').hide();
        var bookId = $(this).prop('id');
        alert(bookId);
    });
```

But instead of Button I would like to put a link button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we do not have link button in mvc, you can do it with `@Html.ActionLink` by overriding the default behaviour of the Action Link.

```
hiddenDiv.Column("",style: "col1",format: @<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Home","Index",null, new { @class="ImgAddition", @onclick="SomeScript(this);"})
</text>)
```

Inorder to display image instead of link you should add the following css

```
.ImgAddition{
     background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;/* add image*/
     display: block;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */

}
```

And finally your script:

```
$('.ImgAddition').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#hiddendiv2').show();
        $('#facilitygrid').hide();
        var bookId = $(this).prop('id');
        alert(bookId);
    });
```

Hope it helps.